# Error in Update query-Visual Studio 2010- Oracle 11g Express edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g

I am trying to perform update action in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with Windows form as the front end and Oracle 11g express as the back end.
I am using C# to code this.

```
private void update_student(string STUDENT_ID, string STUDENT_NAME, string      STUDENT_ADDRESS)
{
      con.Open();

      String sql = "UPDATE STUDENT SET STUDENT_NAME = :STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ADDRESS= :STUDENT_ADDRESS WHERE STUDENT_ID= :STUDENT_ID";

      OracleCommand query = new OracleCommand(sql, con);

      OracleParameter[] updatestud = new OracleParameter[3];

      updatestud[0] = query.Parameters.Add("STUDENT_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, STUDENT_ID, ParameterDirection.Input);
      updatestud[1] = query.Parameters.Add("STUDENT_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, STUDENT_NAME, ParameterDirection.Input);
      updatestud[2] = query.Parameters.Add("STUDENT_ADDRESS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, STUDENT_ADDRESS, ParameterDirection.Input);

      query.ExecuteNonQuery();

      MessageBox.Show("Row Updated");

      con.Close();

}
```

After performing insertion and retrieval actions I am now trying out Update query.

I couldn't understand the flow of parameters and values of the following code that I have used in my application.
I get the following error in the `query.ExecuteNonQuery();` line:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your Student_ID is a string?

Comment: What is your `STUDENT_ID` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`ORA-01722`](http://ora-01722.ora-code.com/)

> The attempted conversion of a character string to a number failed
>   **because the character string was not a valid numeric literal**. Only
>   numeric fields or character fields containing numeric data may be used
>   in arithmetic functions or expressions. Only numeric fields may be
>   added to or subtracted from dates.

This error may cause probably you try to define your `STUDENT_ID` as a `OracleDbType.Varchar2`.

I'm not sure how long your `STUDENT_ID` but you can use `OracleDbType.Int32` instead of.

Like;

```
updatestud[0] = query.Parameters.Add("STUDENT_ID", OracleDbType.Int32 , STUDENT_ID, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

Check out [`OracleType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracletype.aspx) enumeration for more details.

> Specifies the data type of a field or property for use in an
>   OracleParameter.

Comment: Hi Soner! I corrected the piece of code. Thank yu so much for the response. I am still facing the same error. Help!! :( My STUDENT_ID is about 3 digits in length. Ex: 100,123,300,400

Comment: Ha Ha!! I am pretty new to stack overflow. Its really dat evident huh?! :p Anyway any suggestions on it?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking STUDENT_ID may be integer. you are using it as Varchar2, which seems to be the cause of error.

ORA-01722:  invalid number
Cause:  The attempted conversion of a character string to a number failed because the character string was not a valid numeric literal. Only numeric fields or character fields containing numeric data may be used in arithmetic functions or expressions. Only numeric fields may be added to or subtracted from dates.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a ton for ur response. Feel so gud to know someone is listening.. :) Even after changing the Oracle type, the same error is cropping up. Any idea..??

Comment: Convert STUDENT_ID to Integer while passing on to database.updatestud[0] = query.Parameters.Add("STUDENT_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, int.parse(STUDENT_ID), ParameterDirection.Input);  may be u can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi people :) I found the answer myself. Just thought of sharing with you all.

There are 2 methods to accomplish this.

Method 1:

```
 OracleParameter[] updatestud = new OracleParameter[3];
        updatestud[0] = query.Parameters.Add(":STUDENT_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, STUDENT_NAME, ParameterDirection.Input);
        updatestud[1] = query.Parameters.Add(":STUDENT_ADDRESS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, STUDENT_ADDRESS, ParameterDirection.Input);
        updatestud[2] = query.Parameters.Add("STUDENT_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, STUDENT_ID, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

Method 2:

```
            String sql = "UPDATE STUDENT SET STUDENT_NAME = :STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ADDRESS= :STUDENT_ADDRESS WHERE STUDENT_ID= :STUDENT_ID";
        OracleCommand query = new OracleCommand(sql, con);

        OracleParameter p_studid = new OracleParameter();
        OracleParameter p_studname = new OracleParameter();
        OracleParameter p_studaddr = new OracleParameter();

        p_studname.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        p_studname.Value = TxtName.Text;
        query.Parameters.Add(p_studname);

        p_studaddr.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        p_studaddr.Value = TxtAddress.Text;
        query.Parameters.Add(p_studaddr);

        p_studid.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
        p_studid.Value = TxtId.Text;
        query.Parameters.Add(p_studid);
```

You may use any of these methods just remember one thing... Parameters should always be added in the order of the sql. And of course, one must also take care of the OracleDBType.

Also refer to dis page if in case you have doubts-http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18751/building_odp.htm

Thank you all for yur suggestions! :)